# C# .NET Core: conditionally set class properties value to it's default

Tags: c#, .net-core

Let's say I have the following class:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; } = "val1";
    public string Prop2 { get; set; } = "val2";
}
```

And the following code consuming it:

```
var condition = false;

var test = new TestClass
{
    Prop1 =  "nonDefaultValue",
    Prop2 =  condition ? valIfTrue : default,
};
```

Currently `a.Prop2` evaluates to null. Is there a way I can get it to defer to prop2's default value of "val2" in the initializer? I'd rather not explicitly set the false value if I can avoid it.

Edit: without touching TestClass

Comment: What you could do is set a `Prop2Default` string constant in the `TestClass` and use it in property initialization and in your condition.

Comment: I don't want to touch TestClass.  I was hoping there's something built in where I could set it conditionally

Comment: This should be called initial value rather than default value. There is no way to get it from the code. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/properties

Comment: Ok that's what I figured.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could change your property to

```cs
public class TestClass
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; } = "val1";

    private string _prop2 = "val2";

    [AllowNull]
    public string Prop2
    {
        get => _prop2;
        set => _prop2 = value ?? "val2";
    }
}
```

Then assigning `default` or `null` would set it to `"val2"`.

The `AllowNullAttribute` was suggested by Jeppe Stig Nielsen. It suppresses the warning when setting the property to null.

See also: [Preconditions: AllowNull and DisallowNull](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis#preconditions-allownull-and-disallownull)

Comment: If nullable reference types are enabled, the property here could be written either as `[AllowNull] public string Prop2 { get => _prop2; set => _prop2 = value ?? "val2"; }` or else as `[NotNull] public string? Prop2 { get => _prop2; set => _prop2 = value ?? "val2"; }` to signal that it is OK to `set` it to null, but you can still rely on it being nonnull when you `get` it.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, when you use the `default` keyword for a reference type (like a `string`), it indeed sets the value to `null`.for – setting the property to its default value as defined in the class – you can't directly use `default` in this context.

```
  public class TestClass
  {
   private static readonly string DefaultProp1 = "val1";
   private static readonly string DefaultProp2 = "val2";

   public string Prop1 { get; set; } = DefaultProp1;
   public string Prop2 { get; set; } = DefaultProp2;

   public static string GetDefaultProp2()
    {
     return DefaultProp2;
    }
   }
```

Then, in your object initializer, you can use a ternary conditional operator to set `Prop2` to its default value:

```
var condition = false;

var test = new TestClass
{
 Prop1 = "nonDefaultValue",
 Prop2 = condition ? "valIfTrue" : TestClass.GetDefaultProp2(),
};
```

`Prop2` will be set to "val2" if `condition` is `false`, otherwise it will be set to the value you specify for the `true` condition.

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't want to touch the class, you can use the value of a default (untouched) instance.
Eventually, you can add a new `static` property that always yield such instance.

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; } = "val1";
    public string Prop2 { get; set; } = "val2";

    // Default instance. You should ensure nobody can modify it
    public static readonly TestClass Default = new TestClass();
}
```

You can use such new property as following:

```
var test = new TestClass
{
    Prop1 =  "nonDefaultValue",
    Prop2 =  condition ? valIfTrue : TestClass.Default.Prop2,
};
```

The above is the most concise solution I can think of, but it have some drawbacks, like the need to protect the new `Default` property from changes (unless you really want its default values to be modified at runtime); a valid mean could be changing the accessors from `set` to `init`.

However I would prefer to:

- Declare `public` fields (`const` where possibile, otherwise, `static readonly`) named `DefaultProp1` and `DefaultProp2`.
- Initialize the properties using the new fields instead of explicit values.
- Avoid assigning a value to `Prop2` when I know it will be the default one; in complex scenarios it can trigger additional (unwanted or unneeded) code logic.

I would therefore change the class as follows:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public const string DefaultProp1 = "val1";
    public string Prop1 { get; set; } = DefaultProp1;
    public const string DefaultProp2 = "val2";
    public string Prop2 { get; set; } = DefaultProp2;
}
```

And the instantiation as:

```
var test = new TestClass
{
    Prop1 =  "nonDefaultValue",
};
if (condition)
    test.Prop2 = valIfTrue;
```

or as:

```
var test = new TestClass
{
    Prop1 =  "nonDefaultValue",
    Prop2 =  condition ? valIfTrue : TestClass.DefaultProp2,
};
```